# How to preserve Keyboard while presentModalViewController is going

Tags: ios6, ios7, keyboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have IOS6/IOS7 iPhone application.
There is a first dialog (view) with UITextField and secondary modal dialog with another UITextField. I am opening secondary dialog with presentModalViewController from first one.

By default presentModalViewController hides keyboard and opens it after animation is complete. And for smoother user experience, i need keyboard to stay open during presentModalViewController transition

Please help, is it possible at all? What i tried:
- There is no hide/resign to any responders (including textfields in both views)
- There is no endEditing:YES on any controller.
- I tried to create "global" text field and pass focus to it before present call - no luck. 
- I added/removed disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal with YES/NO on both view controllers - does not help either

Seems like this is not possible... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in  second View controller :

[textField2 makeFirstResponder];

Comment: i tryed this already, no luck - still, keyboard animated off then on again